# Group many live web snippets and view/refresh all in one window

Tags: windows, linux, web-browser

Is there any kind of app or utility to show in one window more than one piece of different webpages obtained surfing pages and picking with a rectangular selection style the area of interest? I’ve tried some extensions for both Firefox and Chrome but didn’t found anything as I mean.

Ideally, the application would compile a custom frames window showing each piece of each web page previously selected in it.

I actually need it for Windows, and I consider paid solutions too, but I’d like to find a solution for Windows, Linux, and OS X 10+/ MacOS. Of course a free and open-source cross-platform solution would be great!

Comment: Yes, there are many web apps provided the functionality you described. One still active is: http://www.netvibes.com/en/explore/personal-corpus